# ZFS permission error 'cannot set property' when receiving snapshot from remote machine despite delegated permission

Tags: backup, zfs, snapshot

### Context

I'm setting up [ZFS autobackup](https://github.com/psy0rz/zfs_autobackup) on my home server for offsite backups. All commands printed below are run as non-root.

### Problem

A 'permission denied' error arises originating from the target machine when the following command is issued:

```
(zfs send --large-block --embed --raw --verbose --parsable --props \
 -i @previous_snap localpool/mydataset@newest_snap) | \
(ssh ostsite 'zfs recv -u -o canmount=noauto -v -s \
remotepool/myserver/localpool/mydataset')
```

Full command output:

```
incremental localpool/mydataset@previous_snap   localpool/mydataset@newest_snap 624
size    624
receiving incremental stream of localpool/mydataset@newest_snap into     remotepool/myserver/localpool/mydataset@newest_snap
received 1.31K stream in 1 seconds (1.31K/sec)
cannot set property for 'remotepool/myserver/localpool/mydataset': permission denied
```

### Findings so far

ZFS doesn't explicitly say which property cannot be set, but the only one I'm requesting to be set is `canmount=noauto`. On the target machine, I've delegated some zfs permissions to the receiving user:

```
sudo zfs allow myuser snapshot,receive,create,mountpoint,mount,userprop remotepool/myserver
```

And when I manually execute `zfs set canmount=noauto remotepool/myserver/localpool/mydataset`, this succeeds.

### Questions

1. How can I see which property cannot be set?
2. How can I allow this property to be set (at recv-time)?

## EDIT

It was unrelated to the `canmount` property -- that was being set fine (as long as you've zfs-allowed it). Instead, I was missing the `keylocation` delegation. This is required because sending with `--raw` doesn't de/re-encrypt and therefore wants to change the keylocation to `prompt` upon arrival.

In addition, but this is purely a zfs-autobackup thing, I was missing the `hold` and `release` delegations.

Comment: *And when I manually execute `zfs set canmount=noauto remotepool/myserver/localpool/mydataset`, this succeeds.*  Are you running that as `root`, or as a normal user?  What user are you using to send/receive the snapshots?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've updated the question. the `zfs set` command succeeds as a regular user. The send and receive commands are also issued by regular users.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that low level filesystem operations require root or at least specific elevated rights.

Comment: @paladin hmm. But then I'm confused as to why it works when I manually execute `zfs set canmount ...` (as a regular user with appropriate zfs delegation).

Answer (score 1):

It was unrelated to the `canmount` property -- that was being set fine (as long as you've zfs-allowed it). Instead, I was missing the `keylocation` delegation. This is required because sending with `--raw` doesn't de/re-encrypt and therefore wants to change the `keylocation` to "`prompt`" upon arrival.

In addition, but this is purely a zfs-autobackup thing, I was missing the hold and release delegations.